# Lucene: how to preserve whitespaces etc when tokenizing stream?

Tags: lucene, tokenize, stop-words

I am trying to perform a "translation" of sorts of a stream of text. More specifically, I need to tokenize the input stream, look up every term in a specialized dictionary and output the corresponding "translation" of the token. However, i also want to preserve all the original whitespaces, stopwords etc from the input so that the output is formatted in the same way as the input instead of ended up being a stream of translations. So if my input is

**Term1: Term2 Stopword! Term3
Term4**

then I want the output to look like

**Term1': Term2' Stopword! Term3'
Term4'**

(where **Termi'** is translation of **Termi**) instead of simply

**Term1' Term2' Term3' Term4'**

Currently I am doing the following:

```
PatternAnalyzer pa = new PatternAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_31,
                             PatternAnalyzer.WHITESPACE_PATTERN,
                             false, 
                             WordlistLoader.getWordSet(new File(stopWordFilePath)));
TokenStream ts = pa.tokenStream(null, in);
CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = ts.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

while (ts.incrementToken()) { // loop over tokens
     String termIn = charTermAttribute.toString(); 
     ...
}
```

but this, of course, loses all the whitespaces etc. How can I modify this to be able to re-insert them into the output? thanks much!

============ UPDATE!

I tried splitting the original stream into "words" and "non-words". It seems to work fine. Not sure whether it's the most efficient way, though:

`public ArrayList splitToWords(String sIn) 
{`

```
if (sIn == null || sIn.length() == 0) {
    return null;
}

char[] c = sIn.toCharArray();
ArrayList<Token> list = new ArrayList<Token>(); 
int tokenStart = 0;
boolean curIsLetter = Character.isLetter(c[tokenStart]);
for (int pos = tokenStart + 1; pos < c.length; pos++) {
    boolean newIsLetter = Character.isLetter(c[pos]);
    if (newIsLetter == curIsLetter) {
        continue;
    }
    TokenType type = TokenType.NONWORD;
    if (curIsLetter == true)
    {
        type = TokenType.WORD;
    }

    list.add(new Token(new String(c, tokenStart, pos - tokenStart),type));
    tokenStart = pos;

    curIsLetter = newIsLetter;
}
TokenType type = TokenType.NONWORD;
if (curIsLetter == true)
{
    type = TokenType.WORD;
}
list.add(new Token(new String(c, tokenStart, c.length - tokenStart),type));

return list;
```

}

Comment: your translating a piece of text, but how is that related to Lucene?!

Comment: @milan The actual translation is done by search against a dictionary indexed by Lucene

Comment: I made a wrapper of any tokenizer that produce a tokenstream with the "missing tokens". It is part of a bigger project that is not opensourced yet, so bug me if you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it doesn't really lose whitespace, you still have your original text :)

So I think you should make use of OffsetAttribute, which contains startOffset() and endOffset() of each term into your original text. This is what lucene uses, for example, to highlight snippets of search results from the original text.

I wrote up a quick test (uses EnglishAnalyzer) to demonstrate:
The input is:

```
Just a test of some ideas. Let's see if it works.
```

The output is:

```
just a test of some idea. let see if it work.

// just for example purposes, not necessarily the most performant.
public void testString() throws Exception {
  String input = "Just a test of some ideas. Let's see if it works.";
  EnglishAnalyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input);
  // in some cases, the analyzer will make terms longer or shorter.
  // because of this we must track how much we have adjusted the text so far
  // so that the offsets returned will still work for us via replace()
  int delta = 0;

  TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream("bogus", new StringReader(input));
  CharTermAttribute termAtt = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
  OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = ts.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
  ts.reset();
  while (ts.incrementToken()) {
    String term = termAtt.toString();
    int start = offsetAtt.startOffset();
    int end = offsetAtt.endOffset();
    output.replace(delta + start, delta + end, term);
    delta += (term.length() - (end - start));
  }
  ts.close();

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

}